# Is there a way to multiply a string and an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, string

In Python, there is a way to multiply a string, for example, `"A" * 3` would return `"AAA"`. However, this syntax doesn't work in C++, it just gives me an error, `invalid operands of types 'const char [2]' and 'int' to binary 'operator*'`. Is there a way to multiply a string like this in C++?

Comment: In C++, it is probably better to make a function: `string repeat(string s, size_t n) { string result; result.reserve(s.size() * n); while(n--) result += s; return result; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such operator in C++.

But you can write a function that takes a string and a number as argument, and return the repeated string.

`std::string` also has a constructor that repeats given character a number of times. This may be useful since you used a string of one character as the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload an operator

```
std::string operator*(const std::string& s, unsigned n)
{
    ... // your code here
}
```

Comment: The operator won't be picked up when the left operand is a string literal, though.

Comment: Operators overloads whose all arguments are fundamental or standard types are reserved to the standard.

Comment: Instead of `std::string` how about using `*char`.

Comment: @PalLaden You can't... You must use a class or enum type.

Answer (score 0):

Not really... Although you can right one yourself. C++ is a very different beast to Python. It's much more low level and It is not as forgiving.
C++ deals with "real" memory (as it were).
You can't really just say `"A" * 3`  because before the `"A"` simply used 1 byte of memory if you have 3 `"A"`'s  you need 3 bytes. and since C++'s main benefit is in it's ability to allow the user to author It's memory use, C++ won't just create 3 extra bytes.

You can implement your own version of Python's `"A" * 3` by using the overload operator (although you would have to use a class type like string) C++ provides But I wouldn't really recommend this.

I'd suggest just using a `std::vector` and append the character as many times as you would like.

Also have a think about what you are trying to really do. C++ is all about performance rather than usability. If you are trying to set multiple bytes to a certain value you can use `std::memset`

Comment: <pedantic on>"A" is (at least) two bytes</pedantic>

Comment: where are you getting that information from?

Comment: well the compiler error in the op question already stats it, but "A" is a *null terminated* string, thus "A" is { 'A', '\0' }; thus 2 bytes. I say at least because with utf8 or any other non ascii use, a 'A' may be much larger the a byte.

Comment: I was talking more about the fact that you have to create more memory. rather than the exact size.. Thanks